# aws/s3 gem is not compatible with JRuby

Tags: ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, jruby

I wrote one code to upload file on s3 and it was working fine with Ruby.

I was trying to run same code with jruby but my code is stuck before upload function

Steps which I followed

1. install gem :-

   ```
   jruby -S gem install aws-s3
   ```
2. My code

   ```
   require 'aws/s3'
   local_file = ARGV[0]
   bucket = ARGV[1]
   AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
       access_key_id: 'put_access_key',
       secret_access_key: 'put_secret_access_key')
   base_name = File.basename(local_file)
   AWS::S3::S3Object.store(
       base_name,
       File.open(local_file),
       bucket,
       access: :public_read)
   puts 'Uploaded!'
   url = s3_obj.url_for(
       "#{local_file}",
       "#{bucket}",
       authenticated: false)
   puts "#{url}"
   ```
3. Ran file like this

   ```
   jruby file_name.rb upload_file_name.html bucket
   ```

Comment: Try aws-sdk gem check this out [link](https://gist.github.com/IndianGuru/1194616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a problem in using aws-s3 gem with jruby.

So, I tried it using "aws-sdk" gem

1. `jruby -S gem install aws-sdk`
2. Write code to upload file to s3 as

> ```
> require 'aws-sdk'
> file_name = ARGV[0]
> bucket = ARGV[1]
> AWS.config(
>   access_key_id: 'PUT ACCESS KEY',
>   secret_access_key: 'PUT SECRET KEY')
> s3 = AWS::S3.new
> base_name = File.basename(file_name)
> o = s3.buckets[bucket].objects[base_name].write(File.open(file_name))
> puts '--------------Uploaded!-------------------'
> o.acl = :public_read_write
> url = o.public_url
> puts "#{url}"
> ```

1. Save this in ruby file and run it as give below

> jruby file_name.rb upload_file_name.html path_bucket_where_to_upload
>   
>   Use this [DOC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html) , which give idea how to use "gem aws-sdk"